# Stieltjes integral for monotonically increasing functions.

Tags: calculus, probability, functional-analysis, analysis, probability-theory

Let

$$Z:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$$
$$K:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[1,\infty)$$

monotonically increasing cadlag functions with $K(0)=1$ and $Z(\infty)<\infty$.

I want to show that following Stieltjes integral is finite for all $t\in[0,\infty)$:

$$K(t)\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{K(s)}dZ(s)$$

My attempt so far is following:

$\forall t\in[0,\infty):K(t)<\infty$

\begin{align}Z(\infty)<\infty 
&\Rightarrow \lim_{s\rightarrow \infty}Z'(s)=0\\
&\Rightarrow \frac{Z'(s)}{K(s)}\rightarrow 0\text{ for }s\rightarrow \infty
\end{align}

So my idea would be to find a certain $S\in[0,\infty)$, such that

\begin{align}
K(t)\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{K(s)}dZ(s)&=K(t)\int_0^S \frac{Z'(s)}{K(s)}ds+K(t)\int_S^\infty \frac{Z'(s)}{K(s)}ds\\
&\le K(t)\cdot S\cdot\max_{s\in[0,S)} \bigg[  \frac{Z'(s)}{K(s)} \bigg]+K(t)\cdot\varepsilon,
\end{align}

but I struggle with the right reasoning for the second integral to be $\le \varepsilon$.

Can someone give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $K(t)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{K(s)}dZ(s)$. I think you left something out. Perhaps there is a $t$ in one of the limits of the integral?

Comment: $K(s)=1+s$, $Z(s)=s$, $\int_0^\infty\frac1{K(s)}dZ(s)=+\infty$.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\frac1{K(s)}dZ(s)\le\frac{Z(\infty)}{K(0)}\le Z(\infty)<\infty$

Comment: Hi JGWang, I think in your first example you do not have $Z(\infty)<\infty$, but your second argument should work. Thank you!